# Only allow subkeys of object as a function argument

Tags: typescript

Assume we have an object like this:

```
const MyObject = {
  gloves: {
    gloves1: ...,
    gloves2: ...
  },
  boots: {
    boots1: ...,
    boots2: ...

  }
}
```

where names like `gloves1` are variable. We then create a helper function to get a specific value from `MyObject` i.e.

```
function getValue(category: keyof typeof MyObject, name: string) {
 return MyObject[category][name];
}
```

is there any way to type `name` dynamically based on what `catefory` was passed as argument? So if I pass `gloves` as category name should only be `gloves1` or `gloves2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the example object is invalid I will make up my own, but feel free to replace it:

```
const MyObject = {
  a: { b: "", c: 1, d: true },
  e: { f: false, g: 2, h: "x" }
};

type MyObject = typeof MyObject; // for convenience
```

The right way to do this is to make `getValue()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function.  Assuming some of the nested properties are of different types, you'd also like `getValue()` to return the type corresponding to the particular subproperty.  If so, then you want two generic parameters: one corresponding to the `category`, and one corresponding to the `name`.  Here's how you'd type it:

```
function getValue<K extends keyof MyObject, K2 extends keyof MyObject[K]>(
  category: K, name: K2) {
  return MyObject[category][name];
}
```

This compiles now without error.  `K` is a key of `MyObject`.  And `K2` is constrained to a key of `MyObject[K]`, a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) corresponding to the property of `MyObject` at the `K` index.

Let's see if it works:

```
const good1 = getValue("a", "c"); // number
const good2 = getValue("e", "h"); // string
const bad1 = getValue("a", "h"); // error!
// ----------------------> ~~~
// "h" is not assignable to "b" | "c" | "d"
```

Looks good. Note how the type of `good1` and `good2` are different, and correspond to the particular types of `MyObject.a.c` and `MyObject.e.h` respectively.  And you get the desired error with `bad1` when you use an invalid subproperty key.

Okay, hope that helps!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAsgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAsAFAwwCGAXATCtQET0A0Mw1AjCwCbVQBOAVwwwAvkxJkM1fDABm1WeQA2EDCwDm1AEwsAFgwAe9UTBIiA3CRJQEAB2GJUmbDDw37IWfGTosUS8QksgJg2ACW4DDqGFAAaspCADwA0jAYBlAYYFwQMADWGAie3k5+LMlaaRlZOfmFxY6+2ADayQC6AHwAFBKs5JnqIHwI1MksYOQAtlIwFQCUBL18MQJ8YCVNUM3A-RiDw23NE9NtASJWxKCQsIMgXOyuUTHxSkJd9OTMMPTA9HPmMAA9ICYGABJMUBg+CQrtAoiA7pU8NE4gkMO8MF96Lo-gDgTBoHwwmB1DDwHCUOR7o8US83h8sTj-kCQVC+EMAIQkfEAWj5-IFgqFPI6MAAfhLuSDscYwrkwCBYOQIBAwuoJiglMIoCBvihjAAfb6-GBG+hcehAA)

Answer (score 0):

Your example object is broken:

```
const MyObject = {
    gloves: {
        gloves1: 1,
        gloves2: 2
    },
    boots: {
        boots1: 3,
        boots2: 4
    }
}
```

With generics:

```
function getValue<Category extends keyof typeof MyObject>(category: Category, name: keyof typeof MyObject[Category]) {
    return MyObject[category][name];
}
```

```
getValue("boots", "gloves1"); // Argument of type '"gloves1"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"boots1" | "boots2"'.
```